# can we build T_SQL trigger that changes table in other database

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

I'm working with SQL server 2008, and I want to create in my first database an after update trigger that changes in it's body the data in another database. 
can this be done and how?
kindly help me with the code

thanks

Comment: **Show us** the code you already have, and explain what the concrete problems is that you're facing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are your databases on the same server instance?  If so then just qualify the reference with the database name (e.g. [Database].[schema].[Table]).  This seems to work (I have a database called Staging and another called Tom):

```
USE [Staging]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test]
(
    [Name] VARCHAR(50)
)
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Test] VALUES ('START')
GO

USE [Tom]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test]
(
    [Name] VARCHAR(50)
)
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Test] VALUES ('START')
GO

USE [Staging]
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TestTrigger]
ON [dbo].[Test]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    UPDATE  [Tom].[dbo].[Test] -- Qualified with database name
    SET     [Name] = 'UPDATED FROM [dbo].[TestTrigger]'
GO

UPDATE  [dbo].[Test]
SET     [Name] = 'Testing'
GO

SELECT * FROM [Tom].[dbo].[Test]
GO

DROP TABLE [Staging].[dbo].[Test]
DROP TABLE [Tom].[dbo].[Test]
GO
```